# How to retrieve object values with same key inside an array

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm trying to get (filter) all the objects from a document array that match the same key.

Document Schema example:

```
{
    ...
    country: "ES",
    aut_comms: 
    [
        ...
        {name: "Aragon", province: "Huesca"},
        {name: "Aragon", province: "Teruel"},
        {name: "Aragon", province: "Zaragoza"},
        {name: "Madrid", province: "Madrid"}
        ...
    ]
}
```

If it is possible, im tying to retrieve from the query only the values from the objects that match the same key. Resulting in an array composed like : `["Huesca", "Teruel", "Zaragoza"]`

An Array of objects that match the filter will also do the trick:

```
[
    {name: "Aragon", province: "Huesca"},
    {name: "Aragon", province: "Teruel"},
    {name: "Aragon", province: "Zaragoza"}
]
```

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to get this array by first [unwinding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array and then manipulating it

```
    db.demo.aggregate([
        {
            $unwind:"$aut_comms"
        },
        {
            $match:{"aut_comms.name":"Aragon"}
        },
        {
            $group:{
                _id:null,
                result: {$push:"$aut_comms.province"}
            }
        }
   ])
```

Comment: Thank u so much, this accomplishes  what i needed :)))

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

It is indeed possible to do such query and output in your expected format. You can do either `$unwind` or `$match` first. Personally, I prefer to do a `$match` first as it would limit the number of (unnecessary) documents generated by the `$unwind` operation.

```
db.getCollection('col').aggregate([
    {$match: {"aut_comms.name": "Aragon"}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, "aut_comms": 1}},
    {$unwind: "$aut_comms"},
    {$match: {"aut_comms.name": "Aragon"}},
    {$project: {"province": "$aut_comms.province"}},
    {$group: {
        _id: null,
        province: {$push: "$province"}
    }}
])
```

The output will be:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : null,
    "province" : [ 
        "Huesca", 
        "Teruel", 
        "Zaragoza"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is the same as just doing a find operation and then a projection, which will not yield the array that the OP wants

Comment: Tried this, but it brings me the whole **aut_comms** array. Still not filtering by **name**. Thanx 4 ur help :)

Comment: @inikulin I have updated the answer to your expected format.

Comment: @Andyk. Thanx mate, both of ur responses are great :)))